# Use Histogram data to generate random samples in scipy

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

Suppose I have a process where I push a button, and after a certain amount of time (from 1 to 30 minutes), an event occurs.  I then run a very large number of trials, and record how long it takes the event to occur for each trial.  This raw data is then reduced to a set of 30 data points where the x value is the number of minutes it took for the event to occur, and the y value is the percentage of trials which fell into that bucket.  I do not have access to the original data.

How can I use this set of 30 points to identify an appropriate probability distribution which I can then use to generate representative random samples?

I feel like scipy.stats has all the tools I need built in, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to go about it. Any tips?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that I've never taken a statistics course, so I'm figuring this stuff all out on the fly :)

Comment: Do you have any prior information about the data? (e.g., it comes from a normal distribution, uniform distribution, etc.?)

Comment: Can you share the data?

Comment: I don't know the specific distribution, and in fact that's part of the challenge, is to identify the most appropriate one.  Sample data:

`y = np.array([
0.005995184,
0.012209876,
0.028232119,
0.04711878,
0.087894128,
0.116652421,
0.115370764,
0.12774159,
0.109731418,
0.079767439,
0.068016186,
0.045287033,
0.033403796,
0.029145134,
0.018925806,
0.013340493,
0.010087069,
0.007998098,
0.00984276,
0.004906083,
0.004720561,
0.003186032,
0.003028522,
0.002942859,
0.002780096,
0.002450613,
0.002733441,
0.002217294,
0.002072314,
0.002063246])`  

X values for this are simply 0-30 (or 1-30...?)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any prior information about the underlying function of the data which have been produced, I suggest you to use [`numpy.polyfit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) which fits a polynomial of given degree.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.array([ 0.005995184, ...]) # your array
x = np.arange(len(y))

f = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 10))

x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 30)
y_new = f(x_new)

plt.plot(x,y,'o', x_new, y_new)
plt.xlim([x[0]-1, x[-1] + 1 ])
plt.show()
```

Here is an example for `degree = 10`.

[image]

In order to get an unknown value from the produced polynomial distribution, you simply:

```
f(13.5)
```

which in this case gives:

```
0.0206996531272
```

Comment: This is definitely useful for getting a visual representation of the distribution, but the ultimate goal is to be able to get randomly generated values such that a frequency histogram built from them will be close to one built from the original data.  The .rvs() functions of the scipy.stat.rv_continuous and rv_discrete classes can act as such a generator of random values, but first I have to identify which specific distribution to use, and what the shaping parameters for it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the histogram, piecewise uniform distribution directly, then you get exactly the corresponding random numbers instead of an approximation.

The inverse cdf, ppf, is piecewise linear and linear interpolation can be used to transform uniform random numbers appropriately.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code to show how to use the histogram data directly?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution, but it doesn't feel like a very elegant one.  Basically, take the percentage value (y value) for each x value, multiply by some large number (say, 10,000), then add that many values of x to an array. Continue through all values of x, ending up with a single giant array. This array can then be fed into .fit() methods of the scipy.stats.rv_discrete subclasses.  I'll leave the question open for now as I feel like there must be a better way.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np

xRange = 30
x = scipy.arange(0,xRange+1)

data = [
0.005995184,0.012209876,0.028232119,0.04711878,0.087894128,
0.116652421,0.115370764,0.12774159,0.109731418,0.079767439,
0.068016186,0.045287033,0.033403796,0.029145134,0.018925806,
0.013340493,0.010087069,0.007998098,0.00984276,0.004906083,
0.004720561,0.003186032,0.003028522,0.002942859,0.002780096,
0.002450613,0.002733441,0.002217294,0.002072314,0.002063246]

y=[]
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(int(data[i]*10000)):
        y=np.append(y,i+1)


# creating the histogram
plt.figure(num=1,figsize=(22,12))
h = plt.hist(y, bins=x, normed=True)

dist_names = ['burr','f','rayleigh']

for dist_name in dist_names:
    dist = getattr(scipy.stats, dist_name)
    param = dist.fit(y)
    pdf_fitted = dist.pdf(x, *param[:-2], loc=param[-2], scale=param[-1])
    plt.plot(pdf_fitted, label=dist_name, lw=4)
    plt.xlim(0,xRange)

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```